# How to check where user is relative to a certain location in Android using Location Services?

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am basically creating a check in service, but its meant to be very light. I just need to check it once to allow users to access certain parts of the app only if they are in the area. Unfortunately GPS sometimes (often) never finishes loading and Network is too imprecise. I have tried to compare distance between two locations using `distanceTo`. It works fine... when GPS works! But that means I am at the mercy of the GPS which seems to never work on my Nexus 4 anyways. Anybody have any suggestions on trying to implement this?

Comment: For your case you would definitely need location coordinates in any case. Right? You can also get the location using Network provider, if GPS is not available. You may use distanceTo or can also look for proximity Alert as well.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mention that I use. I use them both. But GPS almost never works. When it does its fine. But Network provider is too imprecise for what I need. I need to figure out if a user is about 200 meters from a specific location. Ideally I want it to be less, but 200 meters is ok.

Comment: I am in a big city in Downtown area. There are lot of tall building around me with 30-40 floors. GPS works fine for me. Since I've checked( 1 week), it has give me lowest 70 meter accuracy. GPS accuracy also varies with the device I guess.

Comment: Yea @ShobhitPuri I started to notice that it works pretty well while I am outside. Indoors it almost never works. Its a tough situation because I need the checkin service to be able to work inside buildings. But I guess I can have a note on the app that says it works better outside.